# Why does App uploaded to play store ask for access to photos/media/files even I have not written it in Manifest file

Tags: android

I have an app in playstore and that app doesn't require any permission except

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
```

Then why does my app uploaded to play store ask for access to photos/media/files even I have not written it in Manifest file.

Comment: except which permission?

Comment: @RajenRaiyarela <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>

Comment: are you using any other third party libs / some other gradle support libs

Comment: NO this is apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "MyApplicationID"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-1.6.html

WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE: Allows an application to write to external storage. Applications using API Level 3 and lower will be implicitly granted this permission (and this will be visible to the user); Applications using API Level 4 or higher must explicitly request this permission.

Changed my  minSdkVersion to 5 not id does not ask for any such permission.